# NodeJS: HTTP GET returns the code instead of JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, http

I have written the following NodeJS code to retrieve the json object from a website

```
var http = require('http');
var url = {
  host: 'www.sample-website.com',
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
};
http.get(url, function(obj) {
  var output = "";
    for (property in obj) {
    output += property + obj[property] ;
}
console.log(output);

})
```

However as response I'm getting some code(some sort of events.js code) that I can't understand (not the HTML code). Need help figuring out where I'm going wrong

Including a snippet for reference ::

```
 // emit removeListener for all listeners on all events
 if (arguments.length === 0) {
   for (key in this._events) {
     if (key === 'removeListener') continue;
     this.removeAllListeners(key);
   }
   this.removeAllListeners('removeListener');
   this._events = {};
   return this;
 }
```

Comment: Just a friendly suggestion, Please use a framework like express or connect

Answer (score 2):

According to [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) API docs, [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) passes a [ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object to its callback. You're currently printing that object (and its parents') properties.

If you want to get the response body, you should register a listener on its data event:

```
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
  console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
});
```

and re-assemble the chunks.

Response code can be accessed via `res.statuscode` property and `res.headers` will give you the response headers in an array.

---

As requested, here's a full sample code:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
// ...
http.request(url, function (res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    console.log('BODY: ');
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        process.stdout.write(chunk);
    });
}).end();
```